# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10?

Tags: python, list

My data looks like this :

```
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1915.0,387.0,1933.0,402.0
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,3350.0,387.0,3353.0,388.0
```

I want to get `1915`, `387`, `1933`, and `402` and the same numbers from below; my file is full of similar data. What I tried :

```
with open('data', newline='') as csvfile:
    results = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in results:
        row = [int(v) for v in row]
        x_coords = row[0:8:2]
        y_coords = row[1:8:2]
        top = min(y_coords)
        bottom = max(y_coords)
        left = min(x_coords)
        right = max(x_coords)
        print (top, bottom,left,right)
```

But I'm getting a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10` error. How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that your csv file *doesn't* contain any integer values.

It contains a string, then floats.

You have to parse as float first, and not the first cell of each row:

```
row = [float(v) for v in row[1:]]
```

if you want integers, convert to int afterwards (with the risk of truncation)

```
row = [int(float(v)) for v in row[1:]]
```

You can save one temporary list creation with `itertools.islice` BTW:

```
row = [int(float(v)) for v in itertools.islice(row,1,None)]
```

Comment: Great explanation i'll accept as soon as i can. Not sure why i got downvoted tho, think i explained the issue well even shared the code didn't just ask for someone to do it for me, but oh well.

Comment: I think you got a DV because you were trying to convert a string to integer. I solved this issue and the next one (parsing floats with integers). It's not a bad question globally. BTW don't forget that you're losing the first path value, if you need it...